# Why can I not choose my UObject class as a parent for a blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I had a blueprint with parent class `Object` which I needed to reference from C++, so I needed to create a C++ class extending `UObject`, defining some of its fields and methods in there and reparenting my blueprint to this new class. It took me ages trying to work out why I couldn't choose this new class as my parent class in the blueprint, until I accidentally fell over the solution in my IDE. Since I hadn't found this anywhere on the internet, I thought I'd post a Q&A style post here for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Blueprintable` to the class's `UCLASS` macro, like this:

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType, Blueprintable)
class MYPROJECT_API UMyClass : public UObject
```

The doc for this macro parameter reads:

> Blueprintable (Unreal Engine reflection specifier)  Exposes this class as an acceptable base class for creating Blueprints. The default is NotBlueprintable, unless inherited otherwise. This Specifier is inherited by subclasses.